Flutter Google Map Best way to check is moved only by user actions
Here I tried 2 ways：

onCameraIdle or onCameraMoveStarted

this func will triggered by not only user actions but also mapController.moveCamera

wrap with Listener

Listener(
  onPointerUp: (event) {
    controller.onRefresh();
  },
  child: _mapView),

But this will triggered by such as map Marker tapped.
There is any way to check is Map is moved/zoomed only by user actions?

you can refine the approach using GestureDetector to track user gestures more precisely.
